# Проблема фиксированного Хедера

Tags: html, вёрстка

Помогите пожалуйста! При тестировании на NEXUS 5, обнаружил такой баг, футер остается на месте когда адресная строка прячется, выходит эффект пустого пространства

скрин до скролла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как только начался скролл, адресная строка пропадает и появляется моя проблема
[image: суть проблемы]

когда останавливается скролл хедер ведет себя нормально, до следующего появления адресной строки

Answer (score 1):

Нашол решение оно мне не подошло, так как скрипт фиксирует адресную строку браузера, мне не подошло так как такое решение крадет у пользователя ~15% видимости. Работает как на Андроиде та и на IOS. Називаеться [iscroll-5](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5).

Answer (score 0):

Не плохо было бы взглянуть на код, но есть подозрение, что хедеру нужно прописать
`position: fixed;` и `left: 0; top: 0;`

Comment: `position: fixed` не работает в большинстве мобильных браузеров

Answer (score 0):

Если блок надо показывать поверх (в плане `z-index`) основного контента, абсолютно спозиционируйте его с `top:0` и оберните в другой с `position: relative`,  расположеный выше основного контента в коде html.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду iOS до 5й версии и Android до 3й версии, то да, с этим проблемы. Но это уже былые времена.

Comment: Под рукой андроид 4.2.2 - в стандартном браузере не работает fixed.

Comment: Проблема не в позиционированию, а именно в position: fixed; нашол нашол инфу что это не новая проблема на Андроиде и на старых IOS